# Forward declaring anonymous structure from C in c++

Tags: c++, structure, forward-declaration

I have a third party C library with an anonymous structure similar to

```
    typedef struct
     {
      ...
      }A;
```

This file is automatically generated through a program, thus can change based on something

Now in a C++ project I accept argument of above type, for example as

```
  void foo(const A & in)
  {
    ...
  }
```

How do I forward declare A in the header file defining the above function?

I have tried :

```
 typedef struct A A;
```

or

```
 struct A;
```

and also

```
 typedef A A;
```

out of curiosity.

However those result in compile time error of redefining the type.
Thanks

Comment: Can you not include the header file for the library that defined `typedef struct { ... } A;`?

Comment: That's not an anonymous `struct` (see 6.7.2.1p13 in the C standard). You cannot have anonymous `struct`s outside a `struct` or `union`.

Comment: C is not C++. Just use the C++ standard. Not clear what you problem is, I see none. What the problem using the `typedef`ed name?

Comment: You cannot forward declare a typedef. You can do that with a tagged struct: `typedef struct tag_A{...}A`

Comment: Someone asked a nearly identical question the other day related to Simulink generated code, and I am really curious to know why the header can't be included.

Comment: @rjp: As I say: it is not clear what the actual problem is. I wonder who upvotes such questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sadly you're out of luck.

`A` is a `typedef` for an untagged `struct`. And you can't forward declare that since you can't refer directly to that `struct`.

Can you change the generator so it outputs `typedef struct A {  ... } A;`? Then it would compile well in both C and C++, and you *could* forward declare that in C++.

Otherwise you have two options: 1. `#include` the file containing the `struct` declaration. 2. Copy the `struct` by hand. Obviously (1) is much more preferable.

Comment: It is an untagged `struct`, not unnamed.

Comment: @Olaf: that's helpful. I was searching for the correct term.

Comment: Just to clarify: I use C terminology and just deduce: the tag is missing, thus I think "untagged" would be the correct name.

Comment: This is a good answer, IMHO. Regarding "Obviously (1) is much more preferable", though, I think it's a tradeoff. It is certainly more robust and DRY; OTOH, since the OP states the file is auto-generated, it might trigger redundant builds. It really depends on the ratio of the frequency of the file generation to the frequency of the untagged struct actually changing.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the generator to provide tag to the structures and it compiles fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because type aliases cannot be forward declared. Only actual types can.